# What program could i code to freeze/hang my program to test watchdog timer?

Tags: c++, linux

what C++ codes could i add to my program which will actually freeze my program so that i can test my watchdog timer. And also how can i cause my OS to freeze too. thanks!

Comment: Just add a tight infinite `while(1){ }` loop to the thread, which you want to test for responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use infinite loops inside your code where you want to run the watch:

```
while(true);

for(;;);

do{
}while(true);
```

Comment: The `for` loop don't need the `true` initial condition, it's enough with `for(;;);`.

Comment: I'd prefer while(true). This is clearer than for(;;;) because for that you need some C knowledge.

Comment: i too prefer it. I was only listing the choices for him

Answer (score 0):

```
void sleep (int sec)
void usleep (int ms)
```

If you want a predetermined duration instead of an endless loop.

Comment: Does `sleep` really freeze the system?

Comment: sleep pauses the current running thread and lets other threads execute.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg But I guess the OP wants precisely the opposite. I mean tight loops which load the CPU have a high probability of triggering a watchdog. Putting a thread to `sleep` will no away help understand or trigger a watchdog. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @PavanManjunath You're right, didn't see the last sentence of the question.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: It depends on what the Watchdog monitors. If the watchdog is configured for monitoring only a particular thread,All you need to do to trigger it is block that thread execution.CPU load is not related in either way.

Answer (score 0):

I always personally liked...

```
cin.get();
```

This will pause the system until you press a key =)

Comment: Will it trigger a `watchdog`?

Answer (score 0):

To cause your OS freeze? Easily...

1.

```
for (;;) {
  fork();
}
```

2.

```
for (;;) {
  malloc(4*1024); // or other size, but not too big, otherwise virtual malloc
}
```

3. in a module(caution!)

```
DEFINE_SPINLOCK(lock);
spin_lock_irq(&lock);
spin_lock_irq(&lock);
```

A sleep function just lead the process to freeze, but OS still normal. To cause OS freeze, you should let a process to obtain too many resource (such as CPU util, memory, or file desc) and doesn't release.

But just to test your watchdog timer for program(not OS), an infinite loop is good enough.